# Low height integer points on a rank variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $M_i$ be fixed rectangular matrices with integer coefficients less than $n$. Consider the variety defined by the condition
$$
 \mathrm{rank}(\lambda_1M_1 + \lambda_2M_2 + ... + \lambda_kM_k)  = 1.
$$

Assume that there is an integral point $(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_k)$ lying on this variety, can we then guarantee that there is an integral point with the height (maximal absolute value of the coordinates) bounded polynomially in $n$ (the exponent may depend on $k$ and the size of the matrices)?

P. S.

It might be related to the Birch-Davenport theorem, so with high probability this question is either known or out of reach for current methods (which would be ok to know), but I couldn't find a reference.

Comment: Are you allowing the degree of the polynomial (i.e. the exponent of $n$) to depend on $k$?

Comment: Yes, and it may also depend on the size of the matrices.